# facebook share ui - share in a group

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to share a link with FB.ui so I will get callbacks for success/ fail
but the FB.ui does not allow to choose where to share ("*on your won timeline*", "*in a group*"....) like the old `sharer.php` did

See screenshot-

[image]
My code renders this popup:

[image]

Is there a way to make the new `fb.ui` popup to allow to share "in a group" like the old one did?

This is my code:

```
FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'some name',
        link: 'http://some url',
        picture: 'http://some image',
        caption: "some text",
        description: "some description"
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          console.log('Post was published.');
        } else {
          console.log('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) and [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) have this limitation unfortunately!

Both dialogs are primarily meant to post/share on **your** timeline only. Feed Dialog do have `to` parameter with it but it can only be the ID of the profile that the story will be published to; and this ID must be a friend who also uses your app.

Comment: The Share dialog absolutely does have a destination option: "The Share dialog gives people the ability to publish an individual story to their timeline, a friend's timeline, a group, or in a private message on Messenger. This does not require Facebook Login or any extended permissions, so it is the easiest way to enable sharing on the web."